# Alternative to ->where() for Arrays in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a function that gets all of the tickets from the Teamwork Desk API. I want to filter out the tickets by date created, but can't use ->where() on an array. Is there an alternative?

Like I've stated before I've tried ->where(), googling didn't help me.

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
public function getTickets() {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => config('teamwork.apilink'),
        'auth' => [config('teamwork.apikey'), 'x'],
        'verify' => false
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('v1/tickets/search.json', [
        'query' => ['sortDir' => 'desc', 'sortBy' => 'updatedAt']
    ])->where('id', 'LIKE', '4477011');

    $json = (string)$response->getBody()->getContents();
    dd(json_decode($json, true));
}
}
```

Without the where it pastes all the tickets, with the "where" it just errors = 'Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::where()'

Comment: '*I want to filter out the tickets by date created*' - How about [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)?

Comment: You could collect the array data and put it into a collection: `collect(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true));`. This way you can use the `where()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to extract the data from your request:

```
$response = $client->get('v1/tickets/search.json', [
    'query' => ['sortDir' => 'desc', 'sortBy' => 'updatedAt']
])->where('id', 'LIKE', '4477011');

$json = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Then you can create a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) from the response array:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$collection = collect($json['items']);
```

Now you can filter the collection, using the methods described in the official documentation I linked you above:

```
$collection = $collection->where('id','4477011');
```

All available methods: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods

Note that this way you will download all the tickets from the teamwork api, and you are filtering the result on your application. If you want to only receive the filtered tickets, you may need to read more carefully the API documentation and create the request accordingly.

Comment: This returns an empty array. Pretty sure it is because there is an array called items in the collection, do you happen to know how I access this?

Comment: Works for me, had to change items name because the array was gone but its functioning! One bonus thing, is there a way to filter to another array for example: $json['items']['moreitems']?

Comment: Just call `collect($json['items']['moreitems'])` to create a collection with that array

Comment: Gives back an error 'Unidentified index', butt I suppose that's an entire diferent question

Comment: It means there is not such an array in the `$json`

Comment: No, but there's an array called responsetime and when I add ['responsetime'] to the collection it gives the error.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solution to get this done. You could use a Laravel Collection for this.

```
$tickets = collect(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true));

$tickets = $tickets->filter(function($ticket) {
    return $ticket['createdAt'] >= now();
});
```

Or like Script47 suggested in the comments you could also use the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method (which Laravel also uses under the hood):

```
$tickets = array_filter($tickets, function($ticket) {
    return $ticket['createdAt'] > now();
});
```

The benefit of using Collections from Laravel is that Laravel provides a lot of methods to make your life easier, however the downside is that in some cases it could be slower. This really depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Personally I like to use the Collection, it looks a little bit cleaner (imo) and saves me some time.